# Not sure why I a getting an error with Matplotlib.PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am writing some code that allows users to enter 2 variables, and then the program is supposed to be able to plot the path of a projectile based on the variables.

I am doing this in Python, using matplotlib.pyplot as my method of plotting graphs. Here is the code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Do Maths and stuff
g = 9.81 #Gravitational Constant
r = int(input("Enter angle of Projectile's launch:: "))
u = int(input("Enter intial velocity of projectile: "))
x = 0

while x <= 90:
   y = x * math.tan(r) - (g*(x*x)) / (2*(u*u)*(math.cos(r)*math.cos(r))
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.show()
```

But when I run this, it says that

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Is an invalid syntax. Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what [lbellomo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41495500/3349443) mentioned, you're missing one parenthesis at the end of `y` definition. More importantly, you never change the value of `x` within the loop, so `while` loop doesn't stop.

Look at the following code; I think it's a better practice to collect data then plot them.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Do Maths and stuff
g = 9.81 #Gravitational Constant
r = int(input("Enter angle of Projectile's launch: "))
u = int(input("Enter intial velocity of projectile: "))
x = 0

xdata=[]
ydata=[]
while x <= 10:
    y = x * math.tan(r) - (g/2)*(x/(u*math.cos(r)))**2
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)
    x+=1
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'-ok')
plt.show()
```

This is the picture when velocity and angle are `2` and `45`, respectively:

[image]

**Suggestion**: Tell people what are the units for angle and velocity (Physics thingy!).

**Final thoughts**: I strongly recommend using `numpy` and defining a function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def projectile(x,v,t):
    """
    x: x values (m)
    v: initial speed (m/s)
    t: launch angle (radian)
    """
    g=9.8 #Gravitational Constant
    y=x * np.tan(t) - (g/2)*(x/(v*np.cos(t)))**2
    return y

r = int(input("Enter angle of Projectile's launch: "))
u = int(input("Enter intial velocity of projectile: "))

xdata = np.linspace(0,10,10)
ydata = projectile(xdata,u,r)
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'-ok')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 spaces instead of 4 inside the while.

Correct indentation:

```
while x <= 90:
    y = x * math.tan(r) - (g*(x*x)) / (2*(u*u)*(math.cos(r)*math.cos(r))
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

Remember that in python the indentation is **VERY** important.

Some suggestions:

Do not change the value of x, it will never leave the while.

Surely you would like to take the `plt.show()` out of the while, to plot all the points together.